# ES6 to use Destructuring Assignment again

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, syntax, variable-assignment

I need to do ES6 Destructuring Assignment repeatedly:

1. **Define** variables from Destructuring Assignment
2. **Update** variables from Destructuring Assignment repeatedly

Like:

```js
function margin() {
  const left=1, right=2, top=3, bottom=4;
  return { left, right, top, bottom };
}

let { left, bottom } = margin();

// later, need to update left, bottom again:
{ left, bottom } = margin();
```

How to make the above code work?
I'm getting `Unexpected token` when updating the variables again.

I know putting them all into a single variable will do, but the question *focus* on whether it is ***possible*** to use Destructuring Assignment *repeatedly*.

Comment: `{ left, bottom } = margin();` starts as a block statement with the no-op expression statement `left, bottom;`. The `=` after the end of the block statement is not syntactically valid. Instead of a block statement, you need a destructuring assignment expression, but in order to correctly disambiguate the `{` at the start, you need to force an [_ExpressionStatement_](//tc39.es/ecma262/#prod-ExpressionStatement) production. Parentheses are the most common way to do this: `({ left, bottom } = margin());`. Yes, it’s possible to use destructuring repeatedly, but you need to get the syntax right.

Comment: the duplicate target has a horrible subject ...

Comment: Exactly @NinaScholz -- there is no way I can find that as my answer on my own search :(.

Comment: i changed the titel a bit.